# How to compare the bias between the two contour plots?

Tags: error-estimation, plotting, matplotlib

I wish to compare the value of the normalized concentration (c+), between two contour plots (one is experimental and another is a simulation). If I don't have a c+ value from the same point on both plots, how can I compare?  (A few data points and interpolation generate them).  I want to know which turbulence model performs better i.e which left-side plot is more similar to the right side plot.  The SKE2 is a modified k epsilon model. TIA
[image: SKE2 vs Experimental]
$$ figure 1: SKE2  vs Experimental$$

[image: SKE vs Experimental]
$$ figure 2:SKE vs Experimental $$

Comment: Define "performs better" :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Which left side (upper or lower) plot is more similar to the right side  plot? :- better

Comment: Define "more similar" then :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Which one has a closer value to the experimental value?

Comment: Define "closer value". The point I want to make, but that you are missing, is that when you compare approach A and approach B to experiment, you need to come up with a *number* $\phi(A)$ and a number $\phi(B)$ that describe a misfit between model and data, so that you can say that $\phi(A)<\phi(B)$ or the other way around. What I'm trying to prod you is to tell us how you want to define the misfit function $\phi$, so that we can tell you how to compute it. There are many ways to define "similarity".

Comment: You might want to try comparing by some norms, L$\infty$ max difference, L2 Root Mean Square of the difference. If you don't have values to compare try to interpolate?